# On button press, push a div below the current div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so when I press a button at the bottom of the page, the current page will slide up and this div will show (examples are pictures below).

I think this will have to use HTML/CSS and JS.

[Picture 1](http://cosmos.team-radiant.com/ss/js.png)

[Picture 2](http://cosmos.team-radiant.com/ss/js2.png)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: the links to the pictures are broken

Comment: You want to click on the button and have the page refocus on the next div, or are you wanting to move a div into a new position in relation to another div?

Comment: see my updated answer, it consists of 5 lines of javascript and it works fine

Comment: @Jonan It works, thanks for helping me out. (also thanks to all whom were involved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `div` you want to slide to a specific `id`, and wrap an anchor tag around the button with the `href` value `#divid`. The page will then slide to the `div` which has the `id` `divid`.

[More info about anchor tags](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html)

You can also do it using javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('div').scrollIntoView();
    }; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! That isn't quite what I want. I want something similar to http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/slide-push-menus/ (press nav bottom). I don't want to use that js they have because I don't need all of the functionality that it has.

Comment: You can't do it without the javascript, because you are basically using a click event for that and handling click events to change multiple elements at once (reduce size of top menu and push an element at bottom) is not yet supported in CSS. Even the link you mentioned uses js: http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/slide-push-menus/js/nav.js

Comment: @Jonan It works, thanks for helping me out. (also thanks to all whom were involved)